# using equation to drawing curve in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I would like to draw a curve logW= a+b*logP, where a = 12, b = -0.8
R = -0.4 of this curve. I would like to use data and look how this curve fits to data. Can I do it in gnuplot?

```
log(f(x)) = a+b*log(P)
a = 12, b = -0.8
fit f(x) 'data.txt' u 1:2 w p via a,b
plot f(x) 'data.txt' u 1:2
```

Does it sounds ok?

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but there are little problems everywhere. Let's try to clean it up.

1) You must define f(x) itself, not log(f(x)).  It is not clear from your statement, but I assume 'P' is the independent variable x?

```
f(P) = exp(a + b*log(P))
```

2) gnuplot commands are separated by semicolons, not commas

```
a = 12; b = -0.8
```

3) 'fit' is not a plotting style, so "with points" makes no sense as part of a fit command

```
fit f(x) 'data.txt' using 1:2 via a,b
```

4) The 'plot' command has two separate pieces: the data and the curve fit to it

```
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2 with points, f(x) with lines
```

[image]